# How to use Microsoft Graph to retrieve extension claims that my B2C custom policy writes?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I using custom policy code like below to write an extension claim called `extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail` as shown in the below code:

[image]

How can I use Microsoft Graph to read/write the value of `extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail` for a given user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created one **custom** user attribute named `mfaByPhoneOrEmail` like below:

[image]

To assign custom attribute value to user via MS Graph API, you need to use below **PATCH** request:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>
{
    "extension_<b2cExtensionsAppIDwithouthyphen>_mfaByPhoneOrEmail": "your_value"
}
```

To get the  `AppID`  of **b2c-extensions**  app, you can check here:

[image]

> Note that, you need **`User.ReadWrite.All`** permission to run Graph
> query of updating user properties.

When I ran below  **PATCH**  request in  [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)  by signing in with B2C user account, I got response like this:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>
{
    "extension_<b2cExtensionsAppIDwithouthyphen>_mfaByPhoneOrEmail": "your_value"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **retrieve** this value from MS Graph API, you can run below query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>?$select=extension_<b2cExtensionsAppIDwithouthyphen>_mfaByPhoneOrEmail
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I ran user flow by selecting **`mfaByPhoneOrEmail`** in Application Claim like below:

[image]

I got **`extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail`** claim successfully in decoded **ID token claims** after signing in like below:

[image]